# Running PHP files with CRON on FreeBSD

Tags: php, cron, freebsd

How can I setup a crontab to execute the PHP file every x amount of time?

I have set `chmod +x` on my PHP file.

My crontab line:

`*/1 * * * * /usr/home/godd/test.php`

... so it should run every one minute, but it doesn't.

I have also added this line to the top of the PHP file:

`#!/usr/local/bin/php`.

But it still not working, any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

cron doesn't automatically pick up the cronfile, did you do something like:

```
crontab cronfile
```

use crontab -l to see what cron thinks it needs to run.

Comment: ... thats indeed I have used `crontab -e`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your system, you may need to invoke the PHP binary like so:

`*/1 * * * * php /usr/home/godd/test.php`

Answer (score 0):

**First**, find the path to "php"

$ which php

/usr/local/bin/php

**Second**, use this path in crontab:

*/1 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/www/essai.php

tested on freeBSD and pfsense